# Compute data from multiple clients simultaneously

Tags: c, linux, concurrency, tcp, epoll

I'm trying to write a server able to handle multiple (more than a thousand) client connections concurrently in C language. Every connection is meant to accomplish three things:

1. Send data to the server
2. The server processes the data
3. The server returns data to the client

I am using non-blocking sockets and epoll() for handling all the connections, but my problem is right in the moment after the server receives the data from one client and has to call a function which spends several seconds in processing the data before it returns the result that has to be sent back to the client before closing the connection.

My **question** is, what paradigm can I use in order to be able to keep handling more connections while the data of one client "is cooking"?

I've been researching a bit about the possibilities of doing it by **creating a thread or a process every time** I need to call the computing function, but I'm not sure if this would be possible given the number of possible concurrent connections, that's why I came here expecting that someone more experienced that me in the matter could shed some light on my ignorance.

---

**Code snippet:**

```
while (1)
                {
                  ssize_t count;
                  char buf[512];
                  count = read (events[i].data.fd, buf, sizeof buf); // read the data
                  if (count == -1)
                    {
                      /* If errno == EAGAIN, that means we have read all
                         data. So go back to the main loop. */
                      if (errno != EAGAIN)
                        {
                          perror ("read");
                          done = 1;
                        }
                      /* Here is where I should call the processing function before
                         exiting the loop and closing the actual connection */

                         answer = proc_function(buf);
                         count = write (events[i].data.fd, answer, sizeof answer); // send the answer to the client
                         break;
                    }
                    ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems sensible to multi-thread or multi-process to some degree to accomplish this. The degree to which you multi-thread or multi-process is the question.

1) You could dump the polling system entirely and use a thread/process per connection. That thread can then stall as long as it wants working on the processing for that connection. You'd then have to decide on creating/killing a thread/process each time (probably easiest) or having a pool of threads/processes (probably fastest).

2) You could have a thread/process for the networky bits and hand off the processing to one other thread. This is less parallel, but it does mean you can at least keep handling network connections whilst you're chopping through the list of work. This gives you control of what processing is being handled at least. It would be easy to prioritise incoming connections this way, whereas option 1 might not.

3) (sort of possible 1 & 2) You could use asynchronous I/O to multiplex your connections. You still to handle the processing in the same way as 1 & 2 above.

You also have the question of threads vs processes. Threads are probably quicker to get going but it's more difficult to ensure data integrity. Processes are going to be more resilient but require more interfacing between them.

You also have to decide on a way to pass data between the threads/processes. This is less of an issue for option 1 as you only have to pass off the connection to the thread. Option 2 may (depending on what your data is) be more of a problem. You could use a message queue for passing the messages about but if you have a lot of data to send shared memory is more appropriate. Shared memory is a pain to engineer for processes but easy with threads (as all threads share the same memory space).

There are performance issues as you get to this scale too. It's worth investigating performance characteristics for these things. The differences to how calls like select and poll scale is significant when you're dealing with a lot of connections.

Without knowledge of what data is being sent and received it's hard to give solid recommendations.

Incidentally, this isn't a new problem. [Dan Kegel](http://www.kegel.com/) had a [good article](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) about it a few years back. It's now out-of-date, but the overview is still good. You should research the current state of the art for the concepts he discusses though.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer @Joe, it features some interesting and instructive ideas. About the answer: The data that is being sent is a single jpeg image (it's binary representation) on every connection (not much more than 100kB).  I've been searching about the option of creating a thread per connection and, although the most appealing of the three for me, but I have my doubts about it's implementation given such a considerable scale. It would be really inspiring if there were some example of someone that has used this approach successfully in a similar case, but I didn't found any.

Comment: I also found promising option 3, but I have no experience with it and the examples I found in the web show very different methods (coroutines, state machines, green threads, etc...) and I don't really know in which one I should focus. (p.s.:C10k is a very good article, but it is hard to find some clear updates to the ideas it presents)